# Hide a div on webform submission using ajax

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms, javascript

I am new to drupal i  am using webform ajax module to submit my webform , its submiting values properly after validating them , but along with this i want to hide a div also on submit . what is the best way to do this

Answer (score 0):

The most effort-free way to hide something i can think to goes trough some CSS.

Inspect the div you want to hide for its id, then just add a rule in your theme CSS

```
#id { display: none; }
```

Comment: but i want to hide div after submission not before submitting

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to add an ID to the submit button, or get the ID thats already assigned to it, and stick a bit of jQuery into the header of that page.

```
(function ($) { 
$('#SubmitButton').click(function() {
     $('#DivYouWantToHide').hide();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Just replace the ID names with the ones you want to use.

Comment: i want to hide my after the thanks message is loaded.

Comment: If you are using ajax webform, and the whole page doesn't reload on submission, then this should do the trick?

Comment: and what about validations , it will hide div even without validations